# Get add to cart button

Tags: magento-1.9

I am building a carousel for products I have all the relevant information e.g name price image but I need an add to cart button for each one of these currently I have got an add to cart button for them all but it adds the main product to the basket for whatever product page I am on. How do I achieve something which adds the relevant product to cart. See my code below.

```
<?php

$category_id = 577; // if you know static category then enter number

$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load    ($category_id); //where $category_id is the id of the category



 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

    $collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter

    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url','small_image','price')); //add product attribute to be fetched

    //$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()'); //uncomment to get products in random order    

    $collection->addStoreFilter();          

    if(!empty($collection))

    {

            foreach ($collection as $_product):

        echo "<div class = 'item'>";
    echo '<img src="' . Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150,150) . '"/>';
           echo "<span class ='prod_name'>";
            echo $_product->getName();   //get product name 
           echo "</span>";  
           echo "<span class = 'prod_price'> ";
            $getPrice =  "£" . $_product->getPrice();

           $snip_string = substr($getPrice , 0 , -2); 
           echo $snip_string;
           echo '</span>';  

           echo "<button type = 'button' title='Add to Cart' id = 'product-addtocart-button' class = 'button btn-cart'
           onclick = 'productAddToCartForm.submit(this)'>";
           echo '<span>';
           echo '<span>';
             echo 'Add to Cart';
           echo '</span>';
           echo '</span>';
           echo '</button>';  

        echo '</div>';    

        endforeach;


    }else

        {

            echo 'No products exists';

    }              

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

simply you can get **add to cart url** just passing the **product object**

```
$_url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
```

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error,  https://justpaste.it/6fi1f @FME

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f   Your code also not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($collection as $_product): ?>

<div class = 'item'>
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(150,150)?>" />
<span class ='prod_name'>
<?php echo $_product->getName();   //get product name ?>
</span>
<span class = 'prod_price'>
    <?php 
    $getPrice =  "£" . $_product->getPrice();
    $snip_string = substr($getPrice , 0 , -2); 
    echo $snip_string;
    ?>

</span>
<button type = 'button' title='Add to Cart' id = 'product-addtocart-button' class = 'button btn-cart'
   onclick = "setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
<span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>';  

</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f   Your code also not working.